# Should I call SDL_DestroyWindow if window creation fails?

Tags: sdl-2

Should I call SDL_DestroyWindow if Window Creation fails? I have the following code below:

```
if(this->Window == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Error: Can't create the SDL Window \n" << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(this->Window);

    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
}
```

Is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the SDL wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyWindow) :

> If window is NULL, this function will return immediately after setting the SDL error message to "Invalid window"

You don't have to call `SDL_DestroyWindow` if you don't have a window in the first place : it will not do anything (other than setting an error message).

You can think of it like `free` in C or `delete` in C++. If you give them `NULL` or `nullptr` (respectively), they do nothing.